# How to fill in listBox based on what items you've checked in a checkedListBox? (using an Access database)

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms, ms-access

I have a database made in Access that looks something like this:

[image: my database tables layout]

I'm trying to work with the data read in from this database in a Windows Forms App (C#). What I'm currently trying to achieve is, populate a checkedListBox with data from the firstItemName column (**done already**) and then based on which of these you've selected, on the click of a button populate a listBox with data from the secondItemName column.

I've done something similar already with an Access query (see below) so I know it's possible, I just have no idea how to achieve this in C#, let alone on a form.

[image: my Access query]

Not sure if I explained it well (I'm not a native English speaker) but basically if e.g. you've checked name 1, 3 and 4, it should populate the listBox with secondName2 (since that's the only one where all those pieces of data are linked).

This is where I'm stuck at:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if(checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(i) == CheckState.Checked)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add( );
            }
        }

    }
```

I'm not sure if my approach is right in the first place and if so, what to do next?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Was it successful? If not, what was the output? Please see [ask], [tour], and the [help] for more details. Then, [edit] your question to include the details required, and your question will get answered.

Comment: I've edited my question, although I haven't got too far with my solution so far

Comment: Seems much better! Your question will be reviewed by other members of SO, and it will most likely be reopened. Thank you for editing your post.

Comment: The Access query you show just joins tables without filter. I am guessing you have not been able to accomplish requirement with an Access query. It won't be simple.